# How do I edit the list of Window Managers that appear in Gnome Login?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, awesome

Ever since I moved to Gnome3 (at least), the login environment has stopped offering some of my window managers as options. A key examples is that I now have to login using TWM first and then select AwesomeWM from the menu it provides in order to get to Awesome. It should be possible to edit the list of window manager (any subset of the ones I have installed). Could someone point me in the right direction?

PS: This question was moved from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594246/how-do-i-edit-the-list-of-window-managers-that-appear-in-gnome-login).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most distros use LightDM for for Gnome3 I believe (Kubuntu user myself so I'm making a few assumptions here). If you are using Ubuntu then the AwesomeWM package has a bug ATM. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/awesome/+bug/1094811

To fix this, the folder `/usr/share/xsessions/` contains a `*.desktop` file which is used to launch your WMs. You simply need to add a new file pointing to the launch script for your other WMs.

Further reading on *.desktop files can be found all over: http://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/

UPDATE: This led the OP to discover that his problem could be resoved by removing the line:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

from `/usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop`.

Comment: deleting the 
    NoDisplay=true
line in /usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop works!

Comment: I've updated the answer to mention this for future visitors. Please update the post with the 'answer' status. Thanks.